# Error: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present, while doing concurrent submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am facing an error - The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present
while there were concurrent users submitting form at same time.
There are 3 servers on google cloud platform which host web site through load balancer.
The "machineKey" in config is the same on all the servers.

Could you please help?

Comment: the possibility is the get request is served by one server which generated anti frogery token while the post request is sent to the other one so it fails to verify the frogery token

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks for the comment. Do you see any setting on GCP load balancer to resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your setup ? Back-end description, load-balancer type etc. Be more descriptive.

Comment: When did the problem occur? Do you visit a certain page or all pages? How did you post the request, ajax or html.beginform()? Are you using @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in the page? Can you show the web.config of application in these 3 servers.